# wget could not works in centos 5.11

Tags: centos

`wget` not works in centOS 5.11.

Do you have any idea?

```bash
sh-3.2# head -n 1 /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
```

```bash
sh-3.2# wget https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.36.0.tar.gz
--2022-10-21 04:19:21--  https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.36.0.tar.gz
Resolving www.cpan.org... 151.101.53.55, 2a04:4e42:d::311
Connecting to www.cpan.org|151.101.53.55|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I pushed the image to docker hub.
You can run it by

```bash
docker run -it zhongpengqun/centos5.11 /bin/sh
```

Comment: Most sites have SSL v2 disabled these days, for security reasons. In fact, many sites have everything below TLS v1.2 disabled. Your best approach to get this working is to setup a proxy on a newer machine and channel all the requests through that machine. https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy, for example, is easy to setup.

Comment: It's a bit complex for me.
I replace `https` by `http`, and it works..